# how to get edits made to my code from github

Tags: github, ruby-on-rails-4, repository, git-fork

I'm working on a project which someone made edits to in github. However, I have no idea how to get the changes into my original file on my computer.

I tried accepting the pull request, and merging the branches, but still the code in my file doesn't change.

I am probably missing something obvious here, as github is still very confusing for me to use. So any help would be appreciated.

I just want to be able to download the edits they made to my code to my original file.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to [merge the pull request *locally on your computer* or *directly on GitHub*](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request).

- If you did merge it directly on GitHub, you still need to do a `git pull` locally, in order to download the new commits.
- If you did merge it locally, you would need a `git push`, to updtate your branch on GitHub with the new commits.